# jQuery.post: I can't post more than one time unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I made a small script to record bugs in my projects

this picture will show you a file name and the bugs it have.
then I used javascript-jquery to save myself some time.
so when I click on an error (the red ones) it will turn to green, and if i click on the fixed error (the green ones) it will turn to red.

[image]

the problem is sometime I click on the wrong error and can't turn it back unless i refresh the page. ex. if I click on error like `tags plugin` (* it turns green *) then I click on `tags plugin` again to turn it back to red it won't turn back, unless I refresh the page then click on it again to turn it.

I checked my code its fine I don't know what the problem is.

in `while` (fetching the error)

```
while ($error = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_errors))
```

here I print the errors

```
<?php
switch ($error['status']) {
        case 'notfixed':
            $error_class    = "error";
            $error_link     = "fix".$error['id']."";
            break;
        case 'fixed':
            $error_class    = "success";
            $error_link     = "unfix".$error['id']."";
            break;
    }

    echo "
    <a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?del=".$error['id']."'>
        <span class='del'>×</span>
    </a>
    <input id='errorid".$error['id']."' value='".$error['id']."' type='hidden'>
    <input id='errorname".$error['id']."' value='".$error['name']."' type='hidden'>
    <div id='newdiv".$error['id']."'>
        <a id='".$error_link."'>
            <span class='".$error_class."'>".$error['name']."</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>";
?>
```

inside the same loop before printing the errors I printed this which the javascript

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $("#fix<?php echo $error['id'] ?>").click(function(){

                var errorid = $("#errorid<?php echo $error['id']?>").val();
                jQuery.post('fix_error.php',{posterrorid : errorid},

                function(data, textStatus){
                    if(data == 1){
                        setInterval(function(){
                                $("#newdiv<?php echo $error['id']?>").html("<a id='unfix<?php echo $error['id']?>'><span class='success'><?php echo $error['name']?></span></a>");
                            }, 1000);
                    }else{
                        setInterval(function(){
                                $("#newdiv<?php echo $error['id']?>").text('error insert');
                            }, 1000);
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#unfix<?php echo $error['id'] ?>").click(function(){

                var errorid = $("#errorid<?php echo $error['id']?>").val();
                jQuery.post('unfix_error.php',{posterrorid : errorid},

                function(data, textStatus){
                    if(data == 1){
                        setInterval(function(){
                                $("#newdiv<?php echo $error['id']?>").html("<a id='fix<?php echo $error['id']?>'><span class='error'><?php echo $error['name']?></span></a>");
                            }, 1000);
                    }else{
                        setInterval(function(){
                                $("#newdiv<?php echo $error['id']?>").text('error insert');
                            }, 1000);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the syntax like this :

```
$("#fix<?php echo $error['id'] ?>").live('click',function(){
.....
});

$("#unfix<?php echo $error['id'] ?>").live('click',function(){
.....
});
```

Because when you click for the first time, you are replacing the html code dynamically, 
so for the next time, when you click that dynamically generated html code will not be noticed, so you have to use .live function.

[REFER](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: I'm newbie with jQuery and JavaScript, what do I do inside the function? I print the html ?

Comment: @AbdullahSalma Read the documentation sam mentioned and experiment a bit with it...

Comment: it's been removed? in v 1.9